# My sudoers setting is not working

Tags: security, sudo, permissions

I tried to use visudo to edit the sudoers setting, and I added a line for my account below the root, here is how I do it

> username   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-get update,/usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade,/usr/bin/apt-get autoclean

But it just doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I have to put this line **at the end**.....
I haven't had this problem when I was using openSUSE..

Comment: Or you could have just added the user to `sudo` group by executing `sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>`.